# Flutter html response not being recorded properly (Maybe Variable-Types? Issue?)

Tags: html, list, flutter

Okay, so this is a confusing one for me...  I HAVE the server-response, but different parts of my program don't seem to be communicating the information properly.

```
void setNumber(String password) async {
  info = await getHistory(password);
  Duration waitTimer = new Duration(seconds: 1);
  new Timer.periodic(waitTimer, (timer) async {
    print('Still checking');
    if (info != null) {
      timer.cancel();
      print('Done updating info.');
    }
  });
}
```

And the server-call I'm using is as follows:

```
Future<List> getHistory(String password) async {
  List<dynamic> data2;
  Duration waitTimer = new Duration(seconds: 1);
  new Timer.periodic(waitTimer, (historyTimer) async {
    http.Response response = await 
    http.post(
      //http response request data redacted for privacy reasons
    );
    if (response.body != null) {
      print('Testing');
      if (response.body != '[]') {
        historyTimer.cancel();
        print(response.body);
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      } else {
        historyTimer.cancel();
        print('No Data');
        return new List();
      }
    }
  });
  print('Should NEVER print');
  return data2;
}
```

Now in my Debug Console I receive the following:

```
flutter: Still checking
flutter: Testing
flutter: [<VERY large response from the server, with all the information I need>]
flutter: Still checking
flutter: Still checking
... 
...
... <repeat>
```

Meaning that for whatever reason, I AM receiving the information I need from the Server...  And it's NOT being sent appropriately to the other part of my program, and recorded.  Maybe there's a Variable-Types issue?  I know from flutter that what I'm being sent after the jsonDecode is a List as I tried to convert it to a Map and it told me you can't convert a List to a Map.  However, even when instantiating everything correctly as a List none of the information is staying inside the list object that is created.  Why?

Comment: 1. The line "should never print" presumably does print immediately and `getHistory` will return immediately returning null. There's nothing in `getHistory` that require it to be `async` as it doesn't await anything. It just creates a timer, prints an incorrect message and returns null. 2. When you construct the second timer you are correctly passing a call back function. Timer callback functions are meant to return `void`, so any return statements in it just finish the callback. No result is returned anywhere; there's nowhere for it to go. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: 3. Starting the still checking timer two lines after await the result isn't helpful. If you've awaited the result, you already have the answer and it won't change.

Comment: The reason the getHistory function is async is it's a place-holder for an api-call that I know works, (I print the data just before the return statement, and the data is printed successfully).  I chose to redact it here, due to an NDA.  And yes, the like "should never print" does get printed first, but again, the actual server-call does get completed afterwards, prints the correct data, and returns the data correctly.  I also tried a variant of this, that resubmits the server-call for the getHistory function if the info is still null, and that never gets done.  and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to find the solution to this one.  The issue was that what I was returning was a Future.  Even though it was a Future, and I was awaiting the response, the response was still in the future format.

So the resolution was as follows.

1) Create a new global variable of List that is set to the server-response.

```
List<dynamic> data2;
```

2) Create a getter-function that allows other parts of the program to retrieve the information contained within that list.

```
List getList() {
  return data2;
}
```

3) Change the line

```
info = await getHistory(password);
```

to:
    await getHistory(password);
    info = getList();

And then pretty much everything worked from that point forward.  I still had issues in understanding the data I was receiving, but that's a wholly different question (Which I've since resolved anyways).

Thank you all for your assistance though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stick the `info = await getHistory(password)` declaration inside the `async Timer.periodic` function body? It's possible that the `info` variable is out of scope, and `info != null` never returns true.

I would debug by adding `print(info)` right above the `info != null` check if that does not fix it.  See below:

```
void setNumber(String password) async {
  Duration waitTimer = new Duration(seconds: 1);
  new Timer.periodic(waitTimer, (timer) async {

    // MOVED INFO DECLARATION
    List info = await getHistory(password);
    // ADDED PRINT
    print(info.toString());

    print('Still checking');
    if (info != null) {
      timer.cancel();
      print('Done updating info.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: While that may be part of it it doesn't seem to actually response the issue I'm having.  Instead the system keeps calling the post-request repeatedly, and crashes vscode (Due to repeatedly printing the VERY large response).